# How to have a shadow inside a CSS mask?

Tags: html, css, svg, shadow, css-mask

Can I have a shadow inside a cutout made by an SVG mask?

Here is the code that I'm working with

`index.html`

```
<div class="content">
    <section id="home-section">
    </section>
    ...
</div>
```

`styles.css`

```
#home-section {
    background: url(img/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-mask: url(img/mask.svg) center/contain no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-size: auto;
}
```

This is the result that I'm getting
[image: CSS mask without shadow]

But this is the result that I want (I've made it in Illustrator):
[image: CSS mask with shadow]

Here is the SVG: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7nGJHeYkgw9Al9BojSVI7f8zKzv4fbu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: share the SVG you are using so we can give you an accurate answer

Comment: Share the svg as code in your question. Clean it if you know how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drop-shadow` filter can help you here if you consider masking like below:

```css
.box {
    height:300px;
    background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1072/800/600) center/cover;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.box div {
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px black);
  height:100%;
}

.box div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:lightblue;
  -webkit-mask:
   /* your mask here */
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >A</text></svg>') left/33% auto,
      url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><text  x="0" y="12" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" >B</text></svg>') center/33% auto,
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) right 10% top 50%/30% 80%,
    /* end of your mask*/
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
   -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
   mask-composite:exclude;
   -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Using your mask the code will be:

```css
.box {
    height:300px;
    background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1072/800/600) center/cover;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.box div {
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px black);
  height:100%;
}

.box div::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:lightblue;
  -webkit-mask:
    url('https://i.ibb.co/JspDMsM/thebirds-mask3.png') center/contain no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
   -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
   mask-composite:exclude;
   -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you used the linear gradient and "mask-composite: exclude"? The last one didn't made  difference for me

Comment: @AsaphSouzaDiniz it depends on the mask. I used exclude to create hole inside the last layer (the linear-gradient one). If your mask is already creating the hole by default then you don't need it. Since I had no access to your SVG I couldn't know such information ;)

Comment: @AsaphSouzaDiniz I have updated the code with your mask